# What constuctor does list initialization use

Tags: c++, string, vector, constructor

I am trying to mimic the stl vector implementation by creating my own vector. I also have created my own version of string that mimics std::string. What kind of constructor do I need to make so that it can use brace enclosed initialization? currently it says Vec has no matching call to Vec::Vec(). I am guessing I have to use std::initializer_list but I don't know where to start.

This is my own version of vector class

```
class Vec{
private:
size_t vectorSize;
size_t vectorCap;
String * myString; //my own version of string
public:
Vec()
{
myString = nullptr;
vectorSize = 0;
vectorCap = 0;
}
explicit Vec(const String& rightObj) //takes String Object
{
   myString = new String[1];
   myString[0] = rightObj; // = is overloaded
   vectorSize = 1;
   vectorCap = 1;
}
Vec(const Vec & rightObj) //copy constructor
{
   if(this == &rightObj)
    {
      return *this;
    }
   delete[] myString;
   vectorSize = rightObj.vectorSize;
   myString = new String[vectorSize];
   for(auto i = 0; i<vecSize; i++)
   {
     myString[i] = rightObj.myString[i];
   }
   vectorCap = vectorSize;
}
// Vec(std::initilizer_list<String> myL)
```

```
#include<vector>
#include <string>
#include "String.hpp"
#include "Vec.hpp"


int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> x {"test1", "test2", "test3"}; //what kind of constructor does this use?
   Vec x {"test1", "test2", "test3"}; // I want to do something like this.
}
```

Comment: Note on the copy constructor: It's a constructor so there can't possibly be a match for `this` and `myString` won't contain an address worth `delete[]`ing. Worse, `myString` hasn't been initialized and could point to something you really, really don't want to `delete[]`. Before you plow ahead adding functionality, I strongly recommend that you test what you already have.

Comment: @user4581301   It should've been `if(this == &rightObj)` .  if it passes this condition isn't it safe to call delete on `myString`

Comment: My point is if you are constructing the object. The only way you can copy construct yourself is to `Vec x(x);` or `Vec x = x;`. Either is a bug so stupid that you should be logging it and aborting the program to make the mistake obvious to the programmer and forcing them to fix it.

Comment: On the other hand, those are both excellent things to do in assignment operator. The blur of a few dozen function calls later `a = something _that_refers_to a;` is a distinct possibility that's worth guarding against.

Comment: Side note: the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) can make constructors a lot easier to write and maintain. Utterly vital if you have a base class or a member variable of a type without a default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> std::vector<std::string> x {"test1", "test2", "test3"}; //what kind of constructor does this use?
> ```

It uses the constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list`.

> What kind of constructor do I need to make so that it can use brace enclosed initialization?

A constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list`.

That's not the only option though. Another is a reference to an array. But such constructor has to be a template function in order to allow the array have multiple sizes.

More generally, another option is for the class to be an aggregate and to not have user defined constructors at all. But that is not an option for your class.

P.S. Avoid bare owning pointers.